# Jquery hide two element and show only one

Tags: jquery

Hi all I have this script and i want when I click `GE` show `EN` end `RU`
after click EN RU or GE show only clicked element, I want it's happened Toggle times

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".main").click(function(){
            alert(123);
        });
    });
</script>

<style>
    .second{
        display:none;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">GEO</div>
    <div class="second">EN</div>
    <div class="second">RU</div>
</body>
```

Comment: could you detail your question a lil bit more ? its hard so guess what you trying to do :) and, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: http://yappe.com/ please go to this site end when see change language panel I want like this

Comment: so, you see GEO and if you click on it, the other two have to show up. after selecting one of these the side should pre reload with the selected param, and after the "reload" the selected value should be main?

Comment: actually this is more code and not just some "where is my bug". you propably have to work with `ul`, guess this should be easyer to display and less css to style. also you need to build some kind of function that get data from selected, move selected to active and last active to the selectables. if you want the same like on the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's very easy :)

```
<body>
    <div class="second">GEO</div>
    <div class="second">EN</div>
    <div class="second">RU</div>
</body>

// language panel script 

$(".second").click(function(){
    $(".second").not(this).fadeToggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you can try:

```
<div class="btn main">GEO</div>
<div class="btn second">EN</div>
<div class="btn second">RU</div>
```

The JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.btn').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('main')) {
            $(".second").show();
        } else {
            $('.main').removeClass('main').addClass('second');
            $(this).removeClass('second').addClass('main');
            $(".second").hide();
        }

    });
});
```

**And here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aa766/)**